# Commandline build failed for swift-openapi-generator - Both Locally and on Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: swift, xcode, azure-devops, openapi, openapi-generator

I am usig Azure DevOps Pipeline to build my Xcode project where I am facing this problem. Xcode version in use is 15.0.1

I have followed the official tutorial [here](https://swiftpackageindex.com/apple/swift-openapi-generator/0.3.5/tutorials/swift-openapi-generator/clientxcode) to setup `swift-openapi-generator` in our project, and it has worked fine when run from within Xcode. Xcode builds the models and client just as it should. However it fails on command line when I run:

`xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release -workspace /Users/zeeshan/Development/MyProjext/myproject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -scheme elvis -destination platform=iOS Simulator,name=MyiPhone,OS=17.0.1 build CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO` with error as in the screenshot below.

[image]

This command line is what we have been using for a while on our Azure DevOps Pipeline for CI so we know the command line works. It started failing only after `swift-openapi-generator` was added as per its official tutorial.

There is no documentation about this error message, and the only couple of sources online which somewhat point to the issue, ask to remove `_OpenAPIGeneratorCore` from the Build Phase Link with Binary settings, but this is not the case since _OpenAPIGeneratorCore was never there in the Link with Binary.

Error message in the log says:
`error: _OpenAPIGeneratorCore is only to be used by swift-openapi-generator itself—your target should not link this library or the command line tool directly.`

I didn't link my target to _OpenAPIGeneratorCore, unless Xcode did it automatically in which case I don't see where to unlink it.

I have tried everything and nothing has worked. Seems like the command line build needs to have an option to trust and enable the swift-openapi-generator library, and I don't know how to accomplish this. Has anyone else encountered this issue and found a solution?

Attached screenshots from the project:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What version of Swift OpenAPI Generator are you using? Your link to the docs is for 0.1.3, which is very old. Can you try again with the latest docs, and as you found, make sure the _OpenAPIGeneratorCore library is _not_ checked for linking with your apps? Only the runtime and transport libraries should be.

Comment: @czechboy thanks for pointing this out. I have updated the link to the correct version. The instructions in the tutorial are the same. I don't see that the OpenAPIGeneratorCore library is checked for linking with the app. Unless Xcode automatically did it in which case I don't see where can I uncheck it.

Comment: It seems it's not a check anymore in recent Xcode, but it should say "None" next to it, in the column for "Targets to add".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after many trial and errors, I figured out that the solution to this problem was to have in the `Target Build Settings` the `Base SDK and Supported Platforms` set to `iOS` only and not to both `macOS` and `iOS`. I tested this by creating two brand new projects with following the `swift-openapi-generator` totorial for each of them to make sure this is true for both the new projects. As soon as you add `macOS`, which is added by default by Xcode 15 for a new project, the commandline build starts to fail.

**The default:**
[image]

**The fix:**
[image]

This change accordingly updates the `project.pbxproj` file to reflect these changes and this results the command line build work fine both locally and in Azure DevOps Pipeline.

[image]